# How to update text file content in zip file in java

Tags: java

I have a zipfile `File filepath = new File("c:/template.zip)`. And I have a `name.txt` inside `c:/template.zip/template/name.txt`. I need to update the contents of name.txt. I tried with below code, but i failed to update it.

```
try {
    FileUtils.writeStringToFile(filepath, "hi", false);
}catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();   
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modifying a text file in a ZIP archive in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11502260/modifying-a-text-file-in-a-zip-archive-in-java)

Comment: you can not write in .zip file, you have to extract the zipentry(file) and then write in it and then zip it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java can not reference a zipped text file content directly, the correct way would be

1. opening the zip file
2. getting the correct file content
3. change the content
   [this is a thread,where Shiva showing how to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11502260/modifying-a-text-file-in-a-zip-archive-in-java)