# changing contents of file inside zip file

Tags: java, file, zip

I followed the below link to edit the contents of a zip file and write to another zip file.

[orignal post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11502260/modifying-a-text-file-in-a-zip-archive-in-java)

when i follow this it seems to work ok except for the last iteration where i get

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry compressed size (expected 1780     
but got 1787 bytes)
at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.closeEntry(ZipOutputStream.java:217)
at  com.dtcc.cdts.components.configdeploy.renameBRKXML.main(renameBRKXML.java:66)
```

i did have the

```
zos.write(buf, 0, (len < buf.length) ? len : buf.length);
```

Please help

Comment: Can share you code where you are facing issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a **new** `ZipEntry` object for the destination file that only uses the name of the `ZipEntry` object obtained from the source.

So change this:

```
ZipEntry entryIn = (ZipEntry) e.nextElement();
```

to something like this:

```
ZipEntry entryIn = (ZipEntry) e.nextElement();
ZipEntry destEntry = new ZipEntry (entryIn.getName());
zos.putNextEntry(destEntry);
```

#### Edit

Here's a quick Google search's result that confirms my approach: http://sourceforge.net/p/retroweaver/bugs/63/

Comment: actually the Original post (the link above ) works jsut fine. I forgot the zip entry in the else block.